# A composition law on $\mathbb{Z}/l\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let $l \geq 1$ be an integer and consider the cyclic group $(\mathbb{Z}/l\mathbb{Z},+)$. Given $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, we write $\bar{n} = n + l \mathbb{Z}$ for the class of $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}/l\mathbb{Z}$.

I would like to show that there is a well-defined composition law $\times$ on $\mathbb{Z}/l\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\bar{m} \times \bar{n} = \overline{m\times n}$ for all $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

$\underline{Attempt:}$

Let the composition law be the additive operation $+$.

Let $\bar{m},\bar{n} \in \mathbb{Z}/l\mathbb{Z}$. Then we have the following:

$\bar{m}+\bar{n} = m + l \mathbb{Z} + n + l \mathbb{Z} = m+n+l \mathbb{Z} = \overline{m+n}$.

$\underline{Question}$

Could it be that this works with the composition law multiplication as well?

Let $\bar{m},\bar{n} \in \mathbb{Z}/l\mathbb{Z}$. Then we have the following:

$\bar{m}*\bar{n} = (m + l \mathbb{Z}) * (n + l \mathbb{Z}) = mn+ml\mathbb{Z}+nl\mathbb{Z}+(l\mathbb{Z})^2 =mn+l\mathbb{Z} = \overline{mn}$.

Would both ways be possible?

**Answer to the question of user Gauss**: When is the multiplication - defined in the second way - a group operation on $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?

I tried to think of it with the example $(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}, *)$. We have: $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}=\{\overline{0}, \overline{1}, \overline{2}, \overline{3}, \overline{4}\}$. Now closure under multiplication is given, since - as shown in my attemp - for any two elements they will in another class (for example $\overline{3} * \overline{4} = \overline{12} = \overline{2}).$ Associativity and neutral element ($\overline{1}$) shouldn't be a problem. What remains is to think about the inverse of such an element. Is that the correct way?

**Inverse**

$\overline{n} \in \mathbb{Z}/l\mathbb{Z}$ is invertible if and only if $gcd(n,l) =1$.

1.) Assume $gcd(n,l) =1$. By Bézouts Lemma we get that $\exists s,z \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $s*n +t*l = 1 \iff sn = 1-t*l \iff sn $ mod $l = (1-t*l)$ mod $l \iff sn$ mod $l = 1 $ mod $l \iff s$ is the inverse element.

2.) Assume $\overline{n}$ is invertible $\iff n * n' + l\mathbb{Z} = 1 + l\mathbb{Z} \iff nn'$ mod $l = 1$ mod $l$, now ther exists a $t \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $nn'$ mod $l = (1-t*l)$ mod $l \iff nn' = 1 - t*l \iff nn' + t*l = 1 \iff gcd(n,l)|1$. The last equivalence follows from Bézouts lemma.

Comment: Addition and multiplication are both well-defined in modular arithmetic

Comment: You are indeed correct - $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is not only a quotient **group** of $\mathbb{Z}$, but also a quotient **ring**. Your proof seems a bit informal, but fine :). I now leave **you** a question: when is this multiplication you defined a group operation on $\mathbb{Z}_n$? Does it satisfy all axioms for any $n$?

Comment: @Gauss May I ask how I could improve my proof so that it is more formal?

Comment: @Gauss Is $\mathbb{Z}_n$ the same as $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Don’t worry about it - what I meant is that distributing the multiplication of classes with the set ($(m + A)(n + A) = mn + mA + nA + A^2$) is a bit of an abuse (or so I’ve been taught), but it usually works. You could say “if $m + k\mathbb{Z} = m’ + k\mathbb{Z}$, then $m - m’ = kp$. Also, $a - a’ = kq$. Thus $ma = (m’ + kp)(a’ + kp)$ and so $ma = m’a’ + k (…)$ and the operation is well defined”

Comment: It is a different notation for the same thing, yes

Comment: I think in the $+$ part, you are actually *defining* $\bar m +\bar n:=\overline{m+n}$, as it is usually done. I mean, what's in between the two, is actually this assumption. Idem for $*$ (which I assume is the previous $\times$).

Comment: @Gauss I've made an edit with my thoughts to your question.

Comment: "Then we have the following: $\bar{m}+\bar{n} = m + l \mathbb{Z} + n + l \mathbb{Z} = m+n+l \mathbb{Z} = \overline{m+n}$": here you are adding sets, not numbers, and the second equality is not sensibile, unless you are *defining* with it the addition of the two sets in the LHS. Using braces would help.

Comment: reij27 You are correct - that is exactly what remains to check

Comment: @Gauss I've made another edit. Would that work? :)

Comment: It would - that’s perfect!